# spring ModelMap implementation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I'm planning to use spring ModelMap. And also like to specify the view name explicitly.
Do you think it's a good idea ?  so that i can use the controller ?

How can I specify a view name with ModelMap? If possible give a small implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer spring [Web MVC tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

You will get spring Web MVC simple example from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/)